# Openssl Encrypting, Decrypting doesn't work with DES

Tags: openssl, des

I'm developing a simple application where there are a Client (C) and a Server (S).

Client gets text from std input, encrypts it, and sends it to the Server.

Since, I don't know if the text from user is multiple of 8 byte( I'm using des),
in my encryption function I always call:
EVP_EncryptUpdate

and then:
EVP_EncryptFinal_ex

```
int encrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *x, char * in, char * buf_out )
{

    int text_len;
    int loutU;
    int loutF;


    text_len = strlen(in) + 1; // i.e : adding '\0'

    if( EVP_EncryptUpdate(x, (unsigned char *)buf_out, &loutU, ( unsigned char*) in, text_len) == 0 )
        return -1;

    if( EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(x, (unsigned char *) &buf_out[loutU], &loutF) == 0 )
        return -1;  

    return loutU + loutF;
}
```

All works fine but only for the first message.

For example if I send as first message:
"12345678" (that are 8 bytes), and as second message:
"hello".
My server will print as second message:
"0x08 0x08 0x08 0x08 0x08 0x08 0x08 0x08 Hello".

0x08 8 times is the padding that on client side EVP_EncryptFinal_ex added.

Another Example:
If first message is "prova daje".
And "Hello" as second.
Server will print as second message: 
"je 0x05 0x05 0x05 0x05 0x05 hello"
Note that je and 0x05 for 5 times are part of first message, indeed:
"prova da" are 8 bytes ,  "je'\0'" are 3 bytes, so 0x05 is  the padding.

How can I avoid this?
I would like to have no dependency between the first and the second message.

Do I have to call `clean_up` each time?

---

EDIT:
I solved, since I called EVP_EncryptFinal_ex I had to call EVP_init to can reuse
the context.